# how to sort JSON string alphabetically in swift?

Tags: ios, uitableview, sorting, swifty-json

I am using SwiftyJSON to parse the JSON from web, and then displaying those values in a tableView. I want to add a functionality to sort the data alphabetically ascending or descending according to the user names. I am new to Swift and having trouble sorting this. I would appreciate any help!

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
super.viewDidLoad()
getContactListJSON()
}

func getContactListJSON(){
let urlString = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"
let urlEncodedString = urlString.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
let url = NSURL( string: urlEncodedString!)
var task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {(data, response, innerError) in
self.json = JSON(data: data)
self.contactsArray = json.arrayValue

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

}
 task.resume()
}
```

This is how I am populating my tableView.

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? UITableViewCell

    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value2, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    }

    cell!.textLabel?.text = self.contactsArray[indexPath.row]["name"].stringValue
    cell!.detailTextLabel?.text = self.contactsArray[indexPath.row]["email"].stringValue
   return cell!

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around a bit I found a more swift-friendly answer. I will leave the Objective-C style below as reference in case it's interesting. Of note – in this first example, the array being sorted must be mutable (var not let) for sort() to work. In the second example with Obj-C sort descriptors a new array is created and the original isn't mutated - similar to sorted()

```
    let contact1: [String: String] = ["name" : "Dare", "email" : "d@me.com"]
    let contact2: [String: String] = ["name" : "Jack", "email" : "j@me.com"]
    let contact3: [String: String] = ["name" : "Adam", "email" : "A@me.com"]

    var contacts = [contact1, contact2, contact3]

    contacts.sort({$0["name"] <  $1["name"]})

    println(contacts)
```

This is corrupted a bit by Objective-C but seems to work. The major benefit of this method over the other is that this is case-insensitive. Although I am sure there is a better way to do the same thing with newer syntax.

```
    let contact1: [String: String] = ["name" : "Dare", "email" : "d@me.com"]
    let contact2: [String: String] = ["name" : "Jack", "email" : "j@me.com"]
    let contact3: [String: String] = ["name" : "Adam", "email" : "A@me.com"]

    let contacts: Array = [contact1, contact2, contact3]

    let nameDiscriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true, selector: Selector("caseInsensitiveCompare:"))

    let sorted = (contacts as NSArray).sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([nameDiscriptor])

    println(sorted)
```

//These print the following

```
    [
        {
            email = "A@me.com";
            name = Adam;
        },
        {
            email = "d@me.com";
            name = Dare;
        },
        {
            email = "j@me.com";
            name = Jack;
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can sort a Swift Array by using `array.sort`

```
self.contactsArray.sort { $0 < $1 }
```

You can refer [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Array.html) for details.

Comment: Because `$0 < $1` is intuitive.

Comment: LOL! @zaph yeah, took me a while to get my head around closure syntax.

Comment: @zaph yeah, the closure syntax might get a while to understand, but its precise, isn't it? Or should I edit and add details of closure syntax also to the answer?

Comment: Note that this will sort contacts starting with a capital letter to the front. In other words `["c", "B", "a"]` will sort to `["B", "a", "c"]`. This may or may not be a problem depending on if you force your contacts to have capitalized names or not.

Comment: Actually I find nothing precise in`$0` or `$1`. That is the same syntax I was using back in 1970 scripting.

Comment: @sasquatch You could add multiple ways of writing that closure. A more verbose version or two would be nice.

Comment: @zaph I'm not a fan of the $0 $1 syntax either.  With Swift closures you can always use a more verbose, but clearer form `self.contactsArray.sort { first, second in first < second }`

Comment: @carl_h `first` and `second` is just as imprecise as `$0` and `$1`. It's just more typing. Either way does not express the data type. It could be anything that's comparable. Whereas if you use something like `firstName` and `secondName` it's pretty clear you're dealing with `String`. Not to say that any way is wrong... I personally don't mind the `$0 < $1` syntax here. It probably won't sort correctly though. I'm assuming @swifty would want a case-insensitive sort.

Comment: @BenKane  Fair enough, `firstName` and `secondName` then for clarity.  It sounds like you're really expressing a dislike of type inferencing  in general, whereas I was expressing a dislike of the shorthand argument names that Swift provides.

Besides, if you want to be completely clear you could always spell it out in full `{ (firstName: String, secondName: String) -> Bool in return firstName < secondName }`

Comment: @carl_h Nope I like type inferencing a lot :) As long as the inference is easy to make. I just felt there was no difference between what you said and what the answer said. I see where you're coming from though.